# Bad practice to re-name model associations in your model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

```
class TransactionItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :transaction
end 

class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :transaction_items

  def items
    self.transaction_items
  end
end



class CategoryItems < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end 

class Category< ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :category_items

  def items
    self.category_items
  end
end
```

In an effort to simplify the interface to `Objects` that have `Items`

are there drawbacks I'm not seeing to this? **or a better way** to achieve this goal?

```
category = Category.first
category.items
# instead of
# category.category_items

transaction = Transaction.first
transaction.items
# instead of
# transaction.transaction_items
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another is by specifying the class (see the [`has_many` options docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-has_many)):

```
has_many :items, :class_name => "CategoryItem"
```

I don't see any major issue with your way, though.

The only caveat would be anything that deals with the associations reflectively (e.g., a documentation tool) would use the "real" name, not the additional method. Not a big deal, but something to be aware of.

Answer (score 1):

When you write:

```
has_many :category_items
```

Rails automagically knows to look for the CategoryItem model. But you are free to decouple the association name and the class it points to

```
has_many :items, :class_name => "CategoryItem"
```